# Running an LDAP Server on Cloudbees

Tags: grails, ldap, cloudbees

I have a simple Grails app that I've written to authenticate against an LDAP server. To develop it, I've installed ApacheDS locally and populated it with an LDIF file. Now I want to deploy it to CloudBees. Is it possible to install an LDAP server on CloudBees?

If not, an alternative seems to be to use the Grails [ldap-server plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ldap-server). However, it doesn't have any documentation on how to configure it. How do I configure this plugin to load an LDIF on startup?

Comment: I found the following tutorial on how to configure the ldap-server plugin, but it fails with a NPE on startup with Grails 2.2.2. http://jamesjefferies.com/2011/01/06/testing-the-grails-spring-security-ldap-combo/

Comment: That plugin is created for Grails 1.1. A lot has changed since then. Why not just start DS yourself? I mean, the Grails application is just a Java/Spring app most of the time anyway. If you can make it work in Java, sure if will work in Grails.

Comment: I was able to install ApacheDS locally and get it working. However, that doesn't help me get it running on CloudBees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, running LDAP in a CloudBees app container/stack won't work because in-bound routing to your application port must be over HTTP/HTTPS.

Alternative 1: host the LDAP server outside of CloudBees (like on your own EC2 server)

Alternative 2: [for the highly motivated] you might be able to get a WebSocket gateway of some kind to work, but you'd special code on the client *and* server side to negotiate the socket stream hand-off outside of the LDAP server and client.  [Client -> WS-Client --> CloudBees --> WS-Server --> LDAP Server]

gripe:  why can't all protocols support virtual hosting like HTTP? -- that would make them much more Cloud-friendly :(

Comment: I ended up going with option 1. Using Ravello Systems to build a VM with ApacheDS installed. Thanks!